# A required field that exists in the view will always make model.state false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following model class:-

```
public class TMSServer_Validation
{
    [Required]
    public string ILOIP { get; set; }
}
```

and the following view :-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerJoin
<div >
  <span class="f">  ILOIP</span>

    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>
```

and the following post action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ServerJoin sj, FormCollection formValues)
{
    //code goes here..
    repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(sj.Server, User.Identity.Name, sj.Resource.RESOURCEID);

    repository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and the following view model class:-

```
public class ServerJoin
{
    public TMSServer Server { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public Technology Technology { get; set; }
    public ComponentDefinition ComponentDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

but whenever i want to edit an object the model state will be False, and the error message indicates that the ILOP field is required, although there is a value for it on the view?

So what is causing this problem ?

**UPDATE**

Th model class is :-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TMSServer_Validation))]     
public partial class TMSServer
        {
            public TMSServer()
            {
                this.TMSServers1 = new HashSet<TMSServer>();
                this.TMSVirtualMachines = new HashSet<TMSVirtualMachine>();
            }

            public int ServerID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ServerModelID { get; set; }
            public int DataCenterID { get; set; }
            public string ILOIP { get; set; }
            public int RackID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> BackUpStatusID { get; set; }
            public int RoleID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> VirtualCenterID { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
            public long IT360SiteID { get; set; }

            public virtual DataCenter DataCenter { get; set; }
            public virtual OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
            public virtual ServerModel ServerModel { get; set; }
            public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }
            public virtual TechnologyBackUpStatu TechnologyBackUpStatu { get; set; }
            public virtual TechnologyRole TechnologyRole { get; set; }
            public virtual TechnologyStatu TechnologyStatu { get; set; }
            public virtual TMSRack TMSRack { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TMSServer> TMSServers1 { get; set; }
            public virtual TMSServer TMSServer1 { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TMSVirtualMachine> TMSVirtualMachines { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Why is your class called TMSServer_Validation, but TMSServer in the View Model?

Comment: because it is a MetadataType class for teh TMSServer ..

Comment: Then, can you post the model class as well?

Comment: can you check my update

Comment: Do you see a value for ILOIP in the FormCollection (formValues)?

BTW, is the Model class you posted here the one that's auto-generated by EF?

Comment: yes it is the auto-generated by EF.

Comment: You only answered half of my question. This is not relevant to your question, but you should create a partial class for your Model, and define the MetadataType on the partial class. Never make changes to the auto-generated code.

Comment: Yes i already have a partial TMSServer class , and i reference the TMSServer_Validation from there..

Comment: And, do you see a value for ILOIP in the FormCollection (formValues)?